# Php include shows code

Tags: php, include

PROBLEM: When I include a php file on the top of my page, instead of running the script, it shows the code.

If I do a simple echo command on the page it works fine, but including a file does not.

I have Googled the hell out of this question and cannot find a solution that solves the problem. Most of the similar problems I've seen are solved by using longhand php tags instead of shorthand.

**The Code**

index.php is in the root folder
init.php is in a folder named 'core' which is in the root folder.

Included File: *init.php*

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOABALS['config'] = array (
    'mysql' => array (
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'db'        => 'lr'
    ),
    'remember' => array (
        'cookie_name'       => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry'     => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array (
        'session_name'      => 'user'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register (function ($class){
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
?>
```

Including Page: *index.php*

```
<?php include '/core/init.php'?>

<!-- Web Page Stuff -->
```

*sanatize.php*

```
function escape ($string){
return htmlentities ($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
```

Why is the php being displayed and not run?

Comment: What is in sanitize.php?  Wondering if there is something in there that is causing it.  Also, what is the page that you are including it in?  If it is a page with a .html extension, you may need to change the settings on your server to parse php in .html pages.

Comment: Well, sanitize.php as posted doesn't have a `<?php` opening tag.  You didn't mention what code is showing, but this is a good candidate.

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked it because it's a minor file. Bishop was right, it was the sanitize file. Thank you bishop! Post it as an answer and I will mark it for you!

Comment: missing a semicolon (;) in index.php, after file include.

Comment: you can solve this by remove the includes one by one and run the code , then you can find which include file creating issue and fix it , please check for the proper <?php and  ?> php tags ,hope this helps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check your sanitize.php file.  I think there is probably an error in there.

Comment: As the contents of sanitize.php are shown, and the <?php and ?> sections are missing, it can be clearly seen that this is the issue, as noted by bishop's comment, as well as Light Bringer's Answer (though his security related commentary is extraneous). An answer that is this vague will not assist people in the future attempting to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the

```
<?php
?>
```

tags in your file to include.

But wow!! So am I to understand that any error with an include during PHP development will shunt the entire library file to the web browser?!!?! So foreign to my concept of full stack programming or cyber-security, where it all would go to a private error log, never exposing the code to the client.

NO WAY IS PHP, NOR APPARENTLY WILL PHP EVER BE MORE SECURE THAN PERL IN MY OPINION!!! So Perl has more server capabilities, it isn't you're missing the willy-nilly 'loose' code that doesn't really require even definitions of variables. Does it dump internal structure code on any error or only on parse errors for instances?!

Comment: Most of this is a rant (and incorrect), rather than an answer. I'd suggest you remove the off-topic ranting.